# Prove that $\frac{m}{n}+\sqrt{3}\frac{p}{q}$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis

If $\frac{m}{n}$ and $\frac{p}{q}$ are rational. Prove that $\frac{m}{n}+\sqrt{3}\frac{p}{q}$ is irrational, given $p\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

1. Can you prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational?
2. Can you prove that if $q \neq 0$ is a non-zero rational number and $x$ is an irrational number, then $qx$ is also irrational?
3. Can you prove that if $q$ is a rational number and $x$ is an irrational number, then $q+x$ is also irrational?

EDIT:

Well, actually, if I want to give you some further hints I'll give you too much information. But since you're still new to the subject I think it's not bad to see some methods first.

I'll only prove the 2nd one. I'll leave the first and third one to you to prove on your own. Suppose that $qx$ is not irrational. Therefore, $qx=p$ where $p \in \mathbb{Q}$. Since $q \neq 0$ I can divide by $q$ and get $\displaystyle x = \frac{p}{q}$. But since $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and the division of two rational number is a third then $\displaystyle x = \frac{p}{q}$ which is contradiction because we assumed $x$ is irrational.

Now use the same trick for the third one. Also, I think by now you should know that $2$ or $3$ aren't any special numbers. You can prove that if $p$ is a prime number then $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational.That's a good exercise to do.

Comment: I've prove only that $\sqrt3$ is irrational

Comment: @JOEF: OK. Now try to prove $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational for any prime number $p$. This is a good exercise. Then try to prove that if $\sqrt{m}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ are irrational and $(m,n)=1$ then $\sqrt{mn}$ is also irrational.  Also, try to apply the same method that I used to solve the third one.

Comment: Let $\sqrt{mn}$ be rational. I have converted the $\sqrt{mn}$ into $\sqrt{m}$ and $\sqrt{n}$. And since $\sqrt{m}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ and (m,n)=1;which contradicts our assumption that $\sqrt{mn}$ is rational. Does the multiplication of two irrational numbers always give an irrational number?

Comment: @JOEF: Nope. $\sqrt{12}.\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{36}=6$. Your argument is not correct.

Comment: I,ll try it again for this. But for the q+x one,I have applied the same techniques you have used above,is it correct?Sorry for not being explicit enough I'm having difficulties to type my answers.Can you tell me exactly what is the meaning of (m,n)=1?Is it the gcd?

Comment: @JOEF: Yes, $(m,n)$ is the $\gcd$. The reason that $\sqrt{12}\sqrt{3}$ fails is because $\gcd(12,3)=3$.

Comment: But If we are told the gcd(m,n)=1, $\sqrt{m}$ $\sqrt{n}$ should be irrational?Can you give me an example where gcd is one and $\sqrt{m}$ $\sqrt{n}$ is rational?. I'm much confused:/.

Comment: @JOEF: That doesn't happen if $\gcd(m,n)=1$. That's what you have to prove. You can use prime factorization and see what you can conclude with that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $\alpha + \beta \sqrt 3 = \gamma$ with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb Q$, we have $\sqrt 3 = \text?$ (solve for $\sqrt 3$). Is this possible?

Comment: For $\sqrt3$,we get it to be irrational

Comment: So $\sqrt 3 = \frac{\gamma - \alpha}{\beta} \not\in \mathbb Q$, with $\gamma, \beta, \alpha \in \mathbb Q$...